# RecyclerView not rendering a card item on the both end

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'd to show the user cards horizontally using a RecyclerView, but I have a problem like the image below.

[image: Strange behaviour of recyclerview]

The card not appears at first, but when I scroll it a little bit, the card shows up suddenly. It looks really weird. Why don't the card rendered from the starts? And it's the same case for the other end of the RecyclerView.

[image: Strange behaviour of recyclerview]

I'm suspecting the `clipChildren` or `clipToPadding`. Is there any solution to this problem without having to put the categories outside of the LinearLayout with a padding?

**HomeFragment.kt**

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root

        setupCategories()
        setupProducts()
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

    private fun setupCategories() {
        val dummy = arrayOf(
            Category(R.drawable.shoes_nike_black),
            Category(R.drawable.yellow_shirt),
            Category(R.drawable.hoodie_gray_big),
            Category(R.drawable.hoodie_pink),
        )
        val spacingInPixels = (Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density * 8).toInt()
        binding.includeContentMain.recyclerViewCategories.addItemDecoration(
            LinearSpacingItemDecoration(spacingInPixels)
        )
        binding.includeContentMain.recyclerViewCategories.adapter = CategoriesAdapter(dummy)
    }

    // other unrelated code...
}
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    tools:showIn="@layout/fragment_home">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCategory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:text="Category"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewCategories"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:overScrollMode="always"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:itemCount="4"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_card_category" />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:text="Top Selling"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewTopSelling"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        app:spanCount="2"
        tools:itemCount="6"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_card_product">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**item_card_category.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#F7BE30"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewCategory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bag"
            tools:src="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

That line of code will help. For **JAVA** and **KOTLIN** use:

```
recyclerViewCategories.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(0, 0);
```

> *`recyclerViewCategories` = `recyclerView`

Comment: Didn't work. Care to explain what is the code about?